# Create a gradient drawable

Tags: android, radial-gradients

I want to create a gradient drawable rectangle to act as background to a view

it should look like this

[image]

right now it looks like this

and it looks like this:

[image]

here is my code for the drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<stroke android:width="10dp" />
<gradient
    android:angle="180"
    android:centerColor="#ffffff"
    android:centerX="0.25"
    android:centerY="0.25"
    android:endColor="#B38340"
    android:startColor="#EBCB92" />
```

what can i do to make it look like i need?

Comment: can i do it in multi xmls ?

Comment: multi xmls? what you mean Lena?

Comment: you can have the frame using nine-patch drawable (but no letters and digits)

Comment: You wouldn't have letters and digits even by using a gradient... ;) +1 for suggesting 9 patches (I was going to do the same).

Comment: i dont need the letters and digits, just the frame